# Finding k-th largest element between two sorted lists both of length k in sublinear O(logk) time?

Tags: algorithm

I am working on designing such an algorithm and am assuming using binary search would work best. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

I have tried this method:

Recursively find mid index for both lists, compare them, and discard the half of the list whose mid element is smaller (as none of those values can be our desired k-th largest). Then we use recursion with the altered lists and new k. However, I am seemingly stuck.

Not looking directly for the answer, rather guidance.

Comment: Are you looking for the median of two sorted arrays of equal lengths?

Comment: You could also do [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect); not sure if the structure of the lists being in order helps the run-time, but probably not enough to make it sub-linear.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

The code uses O(log(k)) -- sublinear:

```
def kth_largest(list1, list2):
    k = len(list1)
    start, stop, mid = 0, k, k + 1
    inf = float('inf')
    while (start <= stop):
        leftAsize = (start + stop) // 2
        leftA = list1[leftAsize - 1] if leftAsize > 0 else -inf
        rightA = list1[leftAsize] if leftAsize < k  else inf
        
        leftBsize = mid - leftAsize
        leftB = list2[leftBsize - 1] if leftBsize > 0 else -inf
        rightB = list2[leftBsize] if leftBsize < k else inf
        
        if leftA <= rightB and leftB <= rightA:
            return  leftA if leftA > leftB else leftB
        elif leftA > rightB:
            stop = leftAsize - 1
        else:
            start = leftAsize + 1
kth_largest([7,10,15],[8,9,12]) 
10
```

---

#### Previous results O(K)

Here is a generic code that finds the kth largest in 2 sorted lists. The lists could be of different sizes. if k is not passed, then it assumes the lists are of the same size and therefore k is taken to be the length of the first list. ie *...two sorted lists both of length k*

```
def kth_largest(list1, list2, k = None):
    len1, len2 = len(list1), len(list2)
    i = j = 0
    k = len1 if k is None else len1 + len2 - k
    while i < len1 and j < len2 and i+j <= k :
        if list1[i] <= list2[j]:    
            result = list1[i]
            i += 1
        else:   
            result = list2[j]
            j += 1
    if i+j <= k:
        if i < len1:
            result = list1[k - j]
        if j < len2:
            result = list2[k - i]
    return result

kth_largest([7,10,15],[8,9,12]) # 3rd largest since k = 3
10
```

Note that the complexity is O(k). Unable to think of a faster algorithm

Comment: This is linear on k

Comment: @wLui155. You are right on that one. Well I dont think I can think of a sublinear algorithm.

Comment: It looked like from the comment to the OP you're aware of an algorithm that finds the median in sublinear time. The same algorithm applies here, as the median can be thought of as a specific index (or two if the combined size is even) into the combined array.

Comment: @wLui155 yes there are algorithms for log N complexity for median of sorted arrays. You are right. a small modification would yield results.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this method:
>
> Recursively find mid index for both lists, compare them, and discard the half of the list whose mid element is smaller (as none of those values can be our desired k-th largest). Then we use recursion with the altered lists and new k. However, I am seemingly stuck.

That approach is perfect! It can indeed be used to get *O*(log *k*) time, provided that our lists give *O*(1) access to arbitrary elements by index. (That is: our lists have to be array-like, rather than linked lists or whatnot.)

First, let me point out that in a list with 2*k* elements, the following are all equivalent ways to think about the element we want:

- the *k*th-to-last element
- the element that precedes exactly *k*−1 other elements
- the element that follows exactly *k* other elements
- the element with index *k* in zero-based indexing
- the second of the middle two elements (e.g. the '3' in [0, 1, **2, 3**, 4, 5])
- the first element of the second half (e.g. the '3' in [0, 1, 2, **3, 4, 5**])

So, consider three cases:

- If *k* = 1 (each list has just one element):

  - We just want the greater of the two elements, no further discussion needed. :-)
- Otherwise, if *k* is odd:

  - Each list has a well-defined middle element; we compare those two.
  - In the list whose middle element is *lesser*, we know that none of the first ⌊*k*/2⌋ elements can be the desired result, because they'd each precede at least ⌈*k*/2⌉·2 ≥ *k* elements.
  - In the list whose middle element is *greater*, we know that none of the last ⌊*k*/2⌋ elements can be the desired result, because they'd each follow at least ⌈*k*/2⌉·2 elements, which is ≥ *k*+1 elements because *k* is odd.
  - So, imagine discarding all of those irrelevant elements, leaving us with two lists of length ⌈*k*/2⌉. Since we wanted the element with index *k*, and we've now discarded ⌊*k*/2⌋ of its predecessors, we now want the element with index ⌈*k*/2⌉ — which is perfect! So we can discard the irrelevant elements and recurse.
  - Note #1: In order to get overall *O*(log *k*) runtime overall, we need to be able to discard the elements in *O*(1) time. In some languages that's trivial; for example, if we're in Java and the original lists are ArrayLists, then we can just use the 'subList' method to get List that's a 'view' into the right part of the original list. In other languages, it's still doable, but we'll need to handle bookkeeping ourselves.
  - Note #2: We don't need to worry much about the case where the middle elements are equal; in that case it doesn't matter which list we discard the *beginning* of and which list we discard the *end* of.
- Otherwise, *k* is even:

  - Each list now has *two* middle elements: one with index *k*/2−1, one with index *k*/2.
  - In the list whose "first" middle element (the element with index *k*/2) is *lesser*, we know that none of the first *k*/2 elements can be the desired result, because they'd each precede at least *k*/2·2+1 = *k*+1 elements.
  - In the list whose "second" middle element (the element with index *k*/2) is *greater*, we know that none of the last *k*/2 elements can be the desired result, because they'd each follow at least *k*/2·2+1 = *k*+1 elements.
  - So, as before, imagine discarding all of those irrelevant elements, leaving us with *k*/2 elements from the start of a list and *k*/2 elements from the end of a list. Since we wanted the element with index *k*, and we've now discarded *k*/2 of its predecessors, we now want the element with index *k*/2 — which is almost perfect! The only bit that's different from above is that this time it's possible that we've discarded all of one list and kept all of the other. We can either explicitly check for that case, or just make sure to write our recursive call in such a way that it doesn't care if the same list was the source of both half-lists. (Of course, the latter approach assumes that we can "discard" elements without actually mutating the original list. As before, a Java ArrayList's 'subList' is perfect for that.)